# How to Request Review with TFS integration plugin for WebStorm?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, webstorm

Trying to find a way to submit Request Review with WebStorm TFS Integration plugin. The action I'm trying to do in Visual Studio: 
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/get-code-reviewed-vs

Is it possible? Maybe there is an additional plugin to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Before you check in your code, you can use **Visual Studio** to ask
>   someone else from your team to review it. Your request will show up in
>   his team explorer, in the my work page.

For now, it's only able to do the code review from VS. Unfortunately, it's not able to request Review with TFS integration plugin for WebStorm.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm a mac user, now having to use windows for work. trying to avoid VS as much as I can... which is probably not possible in this case. thanks anyway